# UnauthorizedException keep responding Internal server error

Tags: nestjs

I'm attempting to create my own npm package for a guard. My guard code looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class AuthModule implements CanActivate {
    constructor() {}
    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext){
        try {
            //some logic
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the log:

```
[Nest] 15736  - 12/25/2023, 4:55:34 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unauthorized
UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at AuthModule.<anonymous> (..\guard\index.ts:56:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (..\guard\dist\index.js:11:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

My code works well until I moved it into my package. Instead of responding with an unauthorized response, it's now giving an Internal Server Error.
I saw the same question but no answer: [UnauthorizedException is deliver as Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284761/unauthorizedexception-is-deliver-as-internal-server-error)

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you testing/using your own package? Are the `@nestjs/*` deps set as `peerDependencies`?